# NestedScrollView setting height to space in between two layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, height, android-nestedscrollview, nestedscrollview

I am trying to keep the back button at the bottom of the page and have the nested scroll view to fill the space below the stats relative layout and the back button at the bottom of the page. It currently fits under the stats at the top but pushes the back button off the bottom of the page since it's fitting the page.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.swapsy.jack.broketoballing.FoodActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linWholePage">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/statsTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textbackground"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgFood"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_food"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp" android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtFood"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgFood"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgFood"
            android:text="@string/_300_300"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/foodBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtFood"
            android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtFood"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/foodbaroutline"
            android:max="300"
            android:progress="150"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/foodprogressdrawable"
            android:padding="2dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgHealth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imgFood"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgFood"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_health"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtHealth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtFood"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgHealth"
            android:text="@string/_300_300"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/healthBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/foodBar"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtHealth"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/healthbaroutline"
            android:max="300"
            android:progress="300"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/healthprogressdrawable"
            android:padding="2dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgClock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imgHealth"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgHealth"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_clock" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgClock"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgClock"
            android:text="@string/timestring"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:id="@+id/txtTime" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imgClock"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgClock"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_money"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:id="@+id/imgMoney" android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMoney"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgMoney"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtTime"
            android:text="@string/_0"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgBank"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imgMoney"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgMoney"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_bank" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtBankBal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtMoney"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgBank"
            android:text="$0"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgBank"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />


        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrFood"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnEatRubbish"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Eat out of a bin                                $0"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnEatBeans"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Eat Beans                                         $2"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnEatSliceOfCake"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Eat Slice of Cake                             $5"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnEatCheeseBurger"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Eat Cheese Burger                        $20"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnEatOrganicMeal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Eat Organic Meal                           $70"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnEatRestaurant"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Eat at Restaurant                          $140"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnEatUltimateMeal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Eat an Ultimate Meal                  $200"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relBack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBack"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="@string/back"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I want it to look like this...

[The look I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO1tc.png)

Comment: Could you show the image you want ?

Comment: Do you want that "btnBack" will be above NestedScrollView ??

Comment: Added an image of what I want it to look like, just need it to not push the back button off the page, and so fit in between the stats at the top and the back button at the button (dynamically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Enclose your nestedScrollView in a Linear Layout with params as

  `<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1">`
- Change the back button's parent to a Linear Layout instead of a relative layout and change its height param as `wrap_content`

Code goes something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linWholePage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.swapsy.jack.broketoballing.FoodActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/statsTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textbackground"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgFood"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_food" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtFood"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgFood"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgFood"
            android:text="@string/_300_300"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/foodBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtFood"
            android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtFood"
            android:background="@drawable/foodbaroutline"
            android:max="300"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:progress="150"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/foodprogressdrawable" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgHealth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imgFood"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgFood"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_health" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtHealth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtFood"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgHealth"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/_300_300"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/healthBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/foodBar"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtHealth"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/healthbaroutline"
            android:max="300"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:progress="300"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/healthprogressdrawable" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgClock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imgHealth"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgHealth"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_clock" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgClock"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgClock"
            android:text="@string/timestring"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgMoney"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imgClock"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgClock"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_money" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMoney"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgMoney"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtTime"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="@string/_0"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgBank"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imgMoney"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgMoney"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_bank" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtBankBal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtMoney"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgBank"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="$0"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrFood"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnEatRubbish"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Eat out of a bin                                $0"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnEatBeans"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Eat Beans                                         $2"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnEatSliceOfCake"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Eat Slice of Cake                             $5"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnEatCheeseBurger"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Eat Cheese Burger                        $20"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnEatOrganicMeal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Eat Organic Meal                           $70"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnEatRestaurant"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Eat at Restaurant                          $140"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnEatUltimateMeal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Eat an Ultimate Meal                  $200"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relBack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBack"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="@string/back"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always remember the XML code is parsed from TOP to Bottom, your relative layout is not being render properly because you have placed it at the end, so just place it above your nested scroll view and in nested scroll view just set layout_above @id of backbtn layout, let me know if you need the code , but i suggest you to try it by your self :)